# How can I prevent long hold backspace from deleting everything?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, samsung-galaxy-s-5

If I am holding down backspace to delete several words, if I hold it down for more than about a second, it will delete everything until the beginning of the line. I would rather it just keep deleting words at a constant pace. I feel like I am working around this "feature" more often than I am using it, ie, I want to delete everything except the first word on a line, and I end up holding backspace for just under a second, waiting, holding it again, waiting, holding again, etc.

The most common occurance is when I want to delete everything after a slash in a web address.

Comment: I'm now using a oneplus 9. tbh I still like the galaxy better overall, but I do appreciate that oneplus' OS does not include the long hold backspace "feature"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible without using a 3rd party keyboard, specifically [SwiftKey](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey&hl=en)

> .. If you continue to hold the backspace key it will speed up.
> **When Gestures are enabled:**
> As well as the same functionality as above, you can additionally delete the last word you type by sliding your finger across the keys from right to left.

[Source - SwiftKey support](https://support.swiftkey.com/hc/en-us/articles/201458582-Is-there-a-quick-way-to-delete-the-last-word-in-SwiftKey-Keyboard-for-Android-)